# os.walk does not find files in directories with trailing white space, how to resolve?

Tags: python, os.walk

I'm writing a python script and running from Linux (not sure if that makes a difference!).

Some directories have a trailing whitespace and `os.walk` finds these directory but does not find any files within those directories even when there are files.

Code:

```
for base_dir, _sub_dirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for file in files:
        print(file)
```

Example:

```
/folder1/folder2/file1
/folder1/folder2 /file2
```

would print

```
"file1"
```

Things I've tried:

1. escaping the root path so all spaces " " become "\ "
2. manually walking the directory with a custom recursive method. when a path is found with a trailing whitespace I tried running a sudo command `"sudo mv {source_path} {dest_path}"` from the python script but I always got `Permission Denied`

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: Whitespace only needs to be escaped in the shell, not in APIs.

Comment: I'm wondering if it has to do with my environment. My target environment is a linux VM but when I run locally on my mac I also get it to work. What environment did you see it working in @Barmar?

Comment: I tested it on a Mac. I'd expect it to work the same on any flavor of Unix, I can't think of a reason why it wouldn't work in a Linux VM.

Comment: I just tried it on Debian Linux, it worked.

Comment: ah so strange :( appreciate you taking the time to try it out

Comment: Isn't it that your python script does not have the exec right on `folder2 ` in which case `os.walk` cannot move inside it?

Comment: @qouify good q, it has the exec right for folder2 (without a space) and all other directories that don't have missing whitespace. when I change the folder names with a trailing whitespace it succeeds. so I don't think it has to do with permissions